# Enlaces automáticos a partir de palabras clave

Tags: html5, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, enlaces-ancla

tengo una duda y estoy buscando la manera más fácil de darme a entender... voy a lo siguiente:

Estoy creando un sitio fan de un juego de rol con wordpress y debo agregar muchas publicaciones que describan cada elemento del juego, cada criatura, cada ítem, cada cosa... como es de esperarse en prácticamente todas las páginas existen referencias a otros elementos, ítems o criaturas que han sido publicados con anterioridad o serán publicados en un futuro... estoy hablando de miles de elementos.

Lo que yo haré será crear publicaciones personalizadas con campos personalizados para cada tipo de post, en varios de esos campos tengo que añadir una serie de palabras (ítems del juego) que deben ser enlaces que apunten a esas publicaciones.

¿Existe alguna manera de crear una lista de palabras clave y que éstas palabras se conviertan automáticamente en enlaces internos en cada aparición de esa palabra en todas las publicaciones de mi sitio?

Supongamos que tengo una serie de campos personalizados (custom fields) para una publicación personalizada (custom post) en el cual tengo que agregar una serie de palabras separadas por coma (,) y necesito que esas palabras se conviertan en enlaces internos que apuntan a otras publicaciones.

Un ejemplo real de esas palabras seria esto:

```
0-5 Small Amethysts, 0-5 Small Emeralds, 0-5 Small Rubies, 0-5 Small Topazes.
```

¿Existe "algo" que - exceptuando los números y las comas (,) - convierta a cada una de esas palabras en enlaces en cada aparición en todas mis publicaciones?

¿No hay alguna extensión donde pueda agregar una lista extensa de palabras y que al guardar simplemente todas las apariciones de esas palabras se conviertan en enlaces en cada publicación donde aparezcan?

En cualquier caso ¿cual sería el modo más eficiente para realizar dicha tarea?

Espero haberme dado a entender, de cualquier modo todo aporte es bienvenido.

Comment: no es una pregunta totalmente basada en opiniones?

Comment: No, no está totalmente basada en opiniones. En todo caso si lo que pregunto no existe entonces debe haber algún modo (o modos) más eficiente que yo estoy ignorando por completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que lo que explicas es la funcionalidad de las tags, en tu custom post type al registrarlo en el área de taxonomía agrega 'post_tag' como soporte, de esta forma

```
taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' )
```

Si estas usando un plugin posiblemente tenga la opción de habilitarlo desde ahí, esto le permitirá usar tags para su publicación personalizada, por lo que podrá crear una lista de palabras clave las cuales al presionarlas redirigirá a la publicación o publicaciones que contengan esas tags, te recomiendo investigar del tema para tener una idea mas amplia.

Las tags usan como vista el archivo archive.php, anexo a eso, en su single debe agregar, en caso de que no este el codigo `<?php get_the_tags(); ?>` para mostrar los tags de su publicación.

Comment: Hey muchísimas gracias!! Investigaré sobre el tema ya que de primera impresión parece que es lo que necesito. En cuanto haga mis pruebas comentaré por acá el resultado.

Comment: Genial, si te funciono mi respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada